# How to send response api for elastic search query result?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I have created a Elasticsearch query which gives me correct result, now i want to send the result as a response for the search API.

I have tried return the response as

```
return JsonResponse(response, status=200)
return Response(response, safe=False) #error response is not JSON serializable
return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(
                {"key": response.title}
            ),
            status=200,
            content_type="application/json"
        ) #AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'title'
```

My code

```
def search(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        q = request.GET.get('q')

        if q:
            p = Q("multi_match", query=q, fields=['title', 'preview_path'])
            s = PostDocument.search().query(p)
            response = s.execute()
        else:
            response = ''

        return HttpResponse(response)
```

My PostDocument Code

```
posts = Index('media')


@posts.doc_type
class PostDocument(DocType):
    print('documents.py')

    class Meta:
        model = Media
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'status',
            'media_source',
            'on_front_page',
            'thumbnail_path',
            'preview_path',
            'published_date',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ]
```

Expected result :
I want to send the response as Json Response.

Actual result, when i use
print(response)

```
<Response: [{'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 0, 0), 'status...}]>
```

Comment: Can you share the error you get when trying ```HttpResponse``` with ```json.dumps```?

Comment: while using HttpResponse with json.dump i'm getting = KeyError: 'title'
and  AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create JSON response by using json.dumps:

```py
HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(
        {"key": response.key}
    ),
    status=200,
    content_type="application/json"
)
```

Edit: As your response object is not an object but a list of objects, you need to do something like this:

```py
response_list = []
for item in response:
    response_list.add(
        {
            "title": item.title,
            "description": item.description
        }
    )

return HttpResponse(
    json.dumps(response_list),
    status=200,
    content_type="application/json"
)
```

Comment: I tried this with response.title but it gives me error, AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'title'.

Comment: The error you get has nothing to do with ```json.dumps```. Just make sure your ```response``` object has title field. Make sure your response model is type of PostDocument, not a list of PostDocument etc.

Comment: the response i have is = <Response: [{'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 0, 0), 'status...}]> and yes object has the title field

Comment: What output do you get when your ```print(response.title)```?

Comment: When i print(response.title) i'm getting, = Internal Server Error: /search/
KeyError: 'title'

Comment: So your error has nothing to do with ```HttpResponse``` or ```json.dumps```. Your response object has no key ```title```. As soon as you retrieve ```title``` from your response object. This answer would return JSON successfully.

Comment: This is the response i have <Response: [{'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 30, 0, 0), 'title'...}]>

Comment: What do you get when you ```print(type(response))``` and ```print(type(response).__bases__)```?

Comment: for (type(response)) i got <class 'elasticsearch_dsl.result.Response'>
and for (type(response).__bases__) i got (<class 'elasticsearch_dsl.utils.AttrDict'>,)

Comment: So your problem is not about turning your data into JSON representation. You have another problem, which is you cannot access fields of your response such as title. Your PostDocument class is a custom class so you need to figure out how to access its fields. When you do that, my answer will work.

Comment: i can access the data using a for loop like         for items in response:
            title = items.title
            print('items.title')
            print(title) and i can access the fields with data but i can't send this as a response

Comment: Thanks the updated solution works can u please tell me how to add one more key like description into  response_list.add({"key": items.title})